# Dynamic Detail View C# Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, dynamic, detailsview

I want to program a dynamic Detail View. Like a user clicked on an Item then he sees the detail view. Now he sees all Values, but when he only want to see a few values, he click on a config Button in this view and a second view opens where he can select and unselect all types of values. Like he dont want to see the Description, the he deselect it in the second view, and it´s no longer visible in the first view.

The only way for me to implement something like this is to programm a Function which generates the first view. The view would be a UI-Element. Which is then returned to the Windows where the UI-Element is set a child of an Element on the Window. But I think this isn´t a good way. How do you would solve this problem?
Thanks for every hint :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you want

List -> Details -> MoreDetails/Edit

Depending on what platform you are creating is a bit different but the idea is the following:

```
<ItemsControl ... x:Name="ItemsList" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
              <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                 <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                       <core:InvokeCommandAction 
        Command="{Binding Datacontext.ShowItemDetails, ElementName=ItemsList}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
         </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </Grid>
     </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Now when you tap the grid you can show a PopupControl with the details and the DataContext:

```
public Command<ItemClass> ShowPopup
{
 get
  {
    return new Command<ItemClass>((i)=>
    {
    //Create the Popup
    });
  }
}
```

In case you are not using MVVM you can add the Command in code behind and place in the page contructor this.DataContext = this; and place the previous command there.

And now create a control for the content of the popup, bind the properties to the item details, now  add another behavior with a command in that control and unhide the controls for edit mode or more details mode

Answer (score 0):

You could have for each detail item a property bool ItemXIsVisible which is bound to a checkbox in the config view, and to the IsVisible property of the X control in the detail view?